# Show a Custom Block on Homepage in Drupal 6

Tags: blocks

I am trying to show a simple block on my home page in Drupal 6.

The Drupal has simple HTML Text.

My question is that how can I show it in my code in let's say Page.TPL.PHP

I searched Internet and tried this:-

```
 if (drupal_is_front_page()) {

      // $block = block_load('block',314);
      // $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
      // print $output;

      $block = module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', '314');
      print $block['content'];
```

The block num is 314 but other than that I am not sure that what user, block or view means in the function. I want to show it on the home page, hence I put it in a condition.

Do I have to leave it disabled or should I enable it in some region so that it can be shown on the Home Page?

Thanksa lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a suitable region to display the block, why not set it to display in that region and in the Block *Visibility settings* configuration under *Show block on specific pages* select *Only the listed pages*. Then in the text area type `<front>` to display it only on the front page.

Comment: This is what I am doing. But my block is showing at the end. I want to change the order and show it on top.

Comment: The easiest way is to define a region where you want it, then place the block in that region. Check out [Regions in PHPTemplate](https://drupal.org/node/29139) on Drupal.org.